# Jquery populating div using jquery and firing click function on it not working while plane html works

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div as follows:

```
<div style="background-color: white;height:400px; padding: 10px;overflow-y:auto;" id="messageDiv">                                               
</div>
```

I am populating the `div` using `jquery` as follows:

```
 $("#messageDiv").html("<span id="spanclick">value</span>");
```

I am using the click event as follows:

```
$("spanclick").click(function(){
alert("here");
})
```

It is not working.

While **if I am directly put the span inside div** without polpulating using jquery then Icall click function then it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the click event handler **after** the `spanclick` element has been added. Also use single quotes for the id attribute to prevent string closure.

```
$("#messageDiv").html("<span id='spanclick'>value</span>");
$("#spanclick").click(function(){
    alert("here");
});
```

Alternatively use a delegate on `messageDiv`:

```
$("#messageDiv").on("click", "#spanclick", function(){
   alert("here");
});
```

---

FYI your question uses `$("spanclick")` instead of `$("#spanclick")`. I assume this is a typo in the question otherwise this would never work.

Answer (score 0):

You have some little mistakes.

Try this:

```
<div style="background-color: white;height:400px; padding: 10px;overflow-y:auto;" id="messageDiv">                                               
</div>
```

and

```
 $("#messageDiv").html("<span id='spanclick'>value</span>");
$("#spanclick").click(function(){
    window.alert("here");
})
```

Here the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cweumc4u/

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click','#spanclick', function(){
       alert("here");
    });
```